# PHP. What is the best way to initialize a variable, FALSE, NULL, 0 OR ''?

Tags: php

Taking into account boolean, strings and integers. What is the best all purpose way to initialize a variable that is going to cause the least amount of problems.

Comment: it all depends on what you want to do with the variable and the rest of your algorithm

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you know where you are going to use the variable. What its data type is going to be.

For instance, array variables: `$test = [];`

If you don't know exactly for what you are going to use the variable then i advise to don't initialize it at all.  In my experience, i never met the scenario where I had to necessary initialize a variable if I wasnt sure whats its nature gonna be.

We do need arrays to be initialized sometimes and for that i gave the example of initializing empty array.

Although initializing a variable with NULL might not serve your purpose if you are planning to use `isset()` function later on for some reason, and for rest options you mentioned, `empty()` function will always return true for them so maybe clear your question a bit to exactly what scenario you are talking for.

Comment: I was wanting initialize variable when starting session that may or may not be used depending what page the user is on. The value is an invoice number selected from the database to be used in different queries on different pages of the website. But my question was meant to be more generic. I was wondering whether there is a basic rule of thumb in PHP?

Comment: In that case, you can initialize it with NULL and later on can check with condition: `if($var !== NULL)`  but as i said in my answer, you cant generalize this idea. One other reason for that is that if you initialize a variable then memory will get located and it will just slow you down in big applications, PHP converts datatype automatically for you for a reason so that it can be faster. You cant treat it like classic C.

Comment: NULL make sense. I take on board the memory reason, I can delete it after testing.

Comment: yes in your case NULL is best option as it doesnt take memory allocation but again in some cases you might need `!empty()` to actually see if variable is set and it will return false even if variable has NULL value. This is why you cannot generalize this idea.

Answer (score 1):

TRUE/FALSE, only use if you want to declare a Boolean variable, like if you want to check if a variable has something then declare another variable with bool

```
$var = "hello";
if ($var == "hello") {
    $new_var = TRUE;
} else {
    $new_var = FALSE;
}
```

NULL variable is use when you want to check if some variable is NULL or not

```
$var = NULL;
if ($var != NULL 
{ echo "something"; }
```

sometimes a variable can have value 0 so we cannot check for the empty variable if we assigned it a 0 value

```
$var = 0;
if ($var != 0)
{ echo "something"; }
```

'' is mostly used to initialize a variable so that if i want to check whether a variable is empty or not and works for string or integer etc

```
$var = '';
if ($var != '')
{ echo "something"; }
```